# Opengl: Performance of atomic counters of atomic counters

Tags: performance, opengl, gpgpu

I have trouble finding believable performance numbers for atomic counters in OpenGl (ARB_shader_atomic_counters).

I am specifically interested in somewhat recent AMD hardware (Southern Islands and later), but more general insights on how this stuff performs on NVIDIA or Intel hardware are much appreciated.

My most pressing questions are:

1. If my shader unconditionally increments the atomic counter, how long is that operation going to take (compared to simple operations like incrementing a local variable)?
2. If the increment is conditional, but highly likely. Does conditional execution change the performance characteristics compared to 1?
3. If the increment is conditional and fairly unlikely (so typically not many increments in parallel). Is this faster than case 1?

The usecase is a workqueue. Each workitem (shader execution) may result in 0-4 new workitems being appended to the workqueue for the next round.

The only performance numbers I could find was people counting the number of fragment shader executions and shading their pixels accordingly. They report a huge performance hit on NVIDIA hardware and "the same performance as other operations" for AMD hardware. The latter sound too good to be true, especially because I have trouble imagining how this could possibly accomplished in hardware. (Bonus points for explaining how the hardware behind this works)

In case it matters: My drivers are recent Catalyst versions on Linux (which are supposedly more or less identical with the Windows versions).

Comment: situations where one pixel every X gets executed but the rest  do not will in general perform badly: http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/259/137

Comment: While your statement is obviously true, I don't see any connection between your comment and performance of atomic counters. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Those performance gain in those "reports" were actually due to how AMD handles dynamic branching compared to NVidia. And probably nothing with how the atmocis work.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for branching in those reports. You increment the atomic counter and derive the color from the return value. It's a one line fragment shader: gl_FragColor = vec4(float(atomicCounterIncrement(ac)/255,0,0,1);